# Spring Security OAuth 2 with traditional Spring MVC

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Issues setting up spring-security-oauth2 (password grant type) for a traditional non-boot spring mvc app.

Able to retrieve access token (step 1).

Get a status 401 when using 'access token' to retrieve secured resource (see step 2).

Curl Commands:

1. Get access token:

   curl -X POST --user clientapp:123456 http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=password&username=adolfo&password=123&scope=read_profile"

Response:

```
{"access_token":"50c7c311-c73a-4a32-bc7e-6801bc64bbe0","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":41545,"scope":"read_profile"}
```

2. Retrieve secured data with access token

   curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/profile -H "authorization: Bearer 50c7c311-c73a-4a32-bc7e-6801bc64bbe0"

Response: Status 401

```
The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.
```

Configurations

//Resource Server Config

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public class OAuth2ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            //@formatter:off
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**");
            //@formatter:on
        }

    }
```

Authorization Server Config

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class OAuth2AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }


        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
                throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("clientapp")
                    .secret("123456")
                    //.autoApprove(true)
                    .redirectUris("http://localhost:9000/callback")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                    .scopes("read_profile", "read_contacts");
        }


        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        }
    }
```

Security Config

```
Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .loginPage("/signin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .failureUrl("/signin-error")
            .permitAll();

}

@Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                //.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .withUser("adolfo")
                .password("123")
                .roles("USER");
    }

}
```

//Controller

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/api/profile")
    public ResponseEntity<UserProfile> profile() {
        String username = (String) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String email = username + "@mailinator.com";
        UserProfile profile = new UserProfile();
        profile.setName(username);
        profile.setEmail(email);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(profile);
    }
```

Init Class

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

     @Override
     protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
     return new Class<?>[]{ SecurityConfig.class, OAuth2AuthorizationServer.class, OAuth2ResourceServer.class,};
     }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{DispatcherConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        DelegatingFilterProxy delegatingFilterProxy =  new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain");
        HiddenHttpMethodFilter hiddenHttpMethodFilter = new HiddenHttpMethodFilter();
        return  new Filter[] {delegatingFilterProxy,hiddenHttpMethodFilter};
    }

}
```

//Logs

```
2018-08-13 15:50:29,333 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher [OrRequestMatcher.java:65] Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2018-08-13 15:50:29,334 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher [AntPathRequestMatcher.java:157] Checking match of request : '/api/profile'; against '/oauth/token'
2018-08-13 15:50:29,334 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher [OrRequestMatcher.java:65] Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
2018-08-13 15:50:29,334 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher [AntPathRequestMatcher.java:157] Checking match of request : '/api/profile'; against '/oauth/token_key'
2018-08-13 15:50:29,334 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher [OrRequestMatcher.java:65] Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
2018-08-13 15:50:29,334 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher [AntPathRequestMatcher.java:157] Checking match of request : '/api/profile'; against '/oauth/check_token'
2018-08-13 15:50:29,334 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher [OrRequestMatcher.java:72] No matches found
2018-08-13 15:50:29,334 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher [OrRequestMatcher.java:65] Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/api/**']
2018-08-13 15:50:29,335 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher [AntPathRequestMatcher.java:157] Checking match of request : '/api/profile'; against '/api/**'
2018-08-13 15:50:29,335 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher [OrRequestMatcher.java:68] matched
2018-08-13 15:50:29,335 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [FilterChainProxy.java:328] /api/profile at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2018-08-13 15:50:29,335 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [FilterChainProxy.java:328] /api/profile at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2018-08-13 15:50:29,335 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [FilterChainProxy.java:328] /api/profile at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2018-08-13 15:50:29,335 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [FilterChainProxy.java:328] /api/profile at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-08-13 15:50:29,335 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher [OrRequestMatcher.java:65] Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2018-08-13 15:50:29,335 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher [AntPathRequestMatcher.java:157] Checking match of request : '/api/profile'; against '/logout'
2018-08-13 15:50:29,336 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher [OrRequestMatcher.java:65] Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2018-08-13 15:50:29,336 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher [AntPathRequestMatcher.java:137] Request 'GET /api/profile' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2018-08-13 15:50:29,336 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher [OrRequestMatcher.java:65] Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2018-08-13 15:50:29,336 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher [AntPathRequestMatcher.java:137] Request 'GET /api/profile' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2018-08-13 15:50:29,336 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher [OrRequestMatcher.java:65] Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2018-08-13 15:50:29,336 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher [AntPathRequestMatcher.java:137] Request 'GET /api/profile' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2018-08-13 15:50:29,337 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.m.OrRequestMatcher [OrRequestMatcher.java:72] No matches found
2018-08-13 15:50:29,337 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy [FilterChainProxy.java:328] /api/profile at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2018-08-13 15:50:29,347 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.o.p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter [OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:165] Authentication request failed: error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid access token: d86d8105-9edf-44dd-94b6-36542cade80f"
2018-08-13 15:50:29,365 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter [HstsHeaderWriter.java:129] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5337f7a
2018-08-13 15:50:29,365 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.o.p.e.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer [DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.java:101] Written [error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid access token: d86d8105-9edf-44dd-94b6-36542cade80f"] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@734d0eb7]
2018-08-13 15:50:29,366 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:119] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

See the entire log [here](https://pastebin.com/4z0CwpkS)

Comment: Your configuration seems to be okay and you should be able to call controller method with valid access token. To find out what goes wrong try to debug `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`. Finally you will see the reason of getting of 401 status code.

Comment: @briarheart removed '@Order' from SecurityConfig, now i get 'invalid_token'

Comment: Perfect! Issue new token and try again.

Comment: Repeated step 1 and 2 above but same invalid token response.

Comment: Is there any additional information in response (description for example) or in server logs?

Comment: @briarheart here is the server response: {"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: 70bb139b-fa6b-48f7-b905-c78bd9bc0a01"}. Entire log [output](https://pastebin.com/4z0CwpkS)

Comment: @briarheart here is a link to a demo https://file.io/ONHGpR

Comment: Finally I've figured out what went wrong. Your application creates two instances of `InMemoryTokenStore` and uses them separately: one for token issuing and another for authentication. It is caused by the configuration in the `WebAppInitializer` class. Move `DispatcherConfig.class` to method `getRootConfigClasses` and just return null from `getServletConfigClasses` method.

Comment: @briarheart That works. Update your answer and I'll accept it. Btw, is there a way to keep the DispatcherConfig.clas inside the getServletConfigClasses?

Comment: I've just edited my post. Please look at it. You will find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` in your stacktrace. I think it is because of the `@Order(2)` annotation that is placed on the `SecurityConfig` class. Your web security configuration clashes with Spring's internal configuration (`org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration`). Try to remove `@Order` annotation from the `SecurityConfig` class.

**EDIT**

Another reason of getting 401 response is using different instances of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore`: one for storing of newly created tokens and another for authentication. It may be caused by the wrong configuration of servlet initializer when implementation of `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer` references (through `ComponentScan` annotation for example) to other configurations that are already declared as root configuration classes. It leads to creation of two application contexts that are clash with each other.

Let's suppose you have three configuration classes:

1. `ServletConfig` that implements `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer`;
2. `AuthorizationServerConfig`;
3. `ResourceServerConfig`.

There are two ways to configure your servlet initializer. The first one is to return `ServletConfig` class from `getServletConfigClasses` method:

```
public class MyServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {AuthorizationServerConfig.class, AuthorizationServerConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {ServletConfig.class};
    }
}
```

By choosing this way you should make sure you do not include classes from root configuration into servlet configuration (do not run component scan from `ServletConfig` class against package where root configuration classes are located).

The second way is to move `ServletConfig` to root configuration classes returning `null` from `getServletConfigClasses`:

```
public class MyServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {ServletConfig.class, AuthorizationServerConfig.class, AuthorizationServerConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is perfectly fine to choose the second way as long as you do not need multiple dispatcher servlets.